# Outputting pi to n decimal places without rounding (user input)

Tags: c++

I am new here, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Pretty much, I am trying to create a program that will allow a user to input a number (n). After the user inputs this number, the program should then output pi to n decimal places, but without rounding the number. For example, if a user inputs "3", I want the output to display 3.141, instead of 3.142.

I managed to write the code to output to n decimal places, but not surprisingly, the output rounds up the number, probably due to the use of the setprecision function. My code can be seen here:

```
int main()

{
double n;
auto pi = 3.1415926535897932;

cout << "Enter the number of digits of pi you want displayed" << endl;
cin >> n;

cout << std::fixed << setprecision(n) << "Your pi value is:" << pi << endl;
return 0;
}
```

How do I change this to keep the program from rounding up the number? My only issue with the code is the rounding problem. How do I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to convert the number to a string with a precision of n+1 and then print only the n first characters.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but to do this, would I be saving pi as a string? Or n? In other words, would I do string pi or string n?

Comment: pi. You convert pi calculated to n + 1, convert it to a string, and then print out only n characters of the string starting from the left.

Comment: You say you want "without rounding", but that's technically impossible. Judging by your examples, you want to "always round down" (aka: Truncate), which is fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck. How would one go about implementing this truncate function into my code? I have no experience with it

Comment: "The program should then output pi to n decimal places, but without rounding the number. For example, if a user inputs "3", I want the output to display 3.141, instead of 3.142." The name for this concept is 'rounding down', and it is also called 'truncation'.  I'm merely providing the name for what you're describing, not an answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck. Yes, I understand, I just figured you were talking about the "trunc()" function. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: And what if the user enters 17? You only entered pi to 16 digits after the decimal place in the program, and a `double` can only hold a limited precision.

Comment: @DanielH. I added more code to deal with that outcome: while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of digits of pi you want displayed (between 1- 
   16<< endl;

    cin >> n;

    if (n > 0 && n <= 16)

    {

    break;

    }

    else

    {

    cout << "Did I stutter? I said between ONE and SIXTEEN.. Try again, 
    child" << endl; Sorry for the horrible formatting. Have no idea how to add the code in a comment like this

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Using a precision of n+1 won't work with that digit is a `9` that gets rounded up to a ten (`0` + carry to a digit you don't want to change).

Answer (score 2):

On implementations that honour the setting in `operator<<`<sup>*)</sup> you can use [`std::fesetround()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto pi{ 3.1415926535897932 };
    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

    for(int n = 0; n < 16; ++n)
        std::cout << "Your pi value is: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(n) << pi << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
Your pi value is: 3
Your pi value is: 3.1
Your pi value is: 3.14
Your pi value is: 3.141
Your pi value is: 3.1415
Your pi value is: 3.14159
Your pi value is: 3.141592
Your pi value is: 3.1415926
Your pi value is: 3.14159265
Your pi value is: 3.141592653
Your pi value is: 3.1415926535
Your pi value is: 3.14159265358
Your pi value is: 3.141592653589
Your pi value is: 3.1415926535897
Your pi value is: 3.14159265358979
Your pi value is: 3.141592653589793
```

*) Microsofts standard library implementation does not.

---

Another simple solution would be to use a `std::stringstream` and print the digits required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto pi{ 3.1415926535897932 };
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(16u) << pi;

    for (int n = 1; n < 18; ++n) {
        if (n != 2) // no point in printing "3" and "3." additionally.
            std::cout << "Your pi value is: " << ss.str().substr(0, n) << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

With user input:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto pi{ 3.1415926535897932 };
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(16) << pi;

    unsigned digits;
    while (std::cout << "How many digits of pi do you want? (up to 16) ",
           !(std::cin >> digits) || digits > 16)
    {
        std::cerr << "Input Error :(\n\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    std::cout << "Your pi value is: " << ss.str().substr(0, 2 + digits) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the work, and this does in fact output pi with the values rounded down, but how would one make this a program where the user can enter the number to which they want the decimal place? I tried adding a cin command using the stringstream code but was getting very weird outputs. I have been trying for hours, but every time i get a valid output it just rounds up. Slowly starting to give up haha